# Ho can I show the first tab

Tags: tabs

I am having trouble with showing the first tab by default. Right now it's showing the second tab by default. Please help. Thanks

What I want to do is present the first tab automatically when someone opens the page.

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="tabs hideOnSearch">                                 
                    <span class="overview-tab">
                        <?php _e('Detalii','language');?>
                    </span>     
                        <span class="features-tab active">
                        <?php _e('Features','language');?>
                    </span>     
                        <?php $video_source = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_meta_box_source', true);
                                    $video_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_meta_box_videoid', true);                   
                                    if(($video_source == "vimeo") && !empty($video_id)){ ?>
                                    <?php _e('Video','language');?> 
                                                                        <?php } elseif(( $video_source == "youtube") && !empty($video_id)){ ?>
                                    <span class="video-tab"><?php _e('Video','language');?></span> 
                                    <?php  } ?>                                                                 
                    <div class="item-list"> 
<ul class="overview">
                                <?php   $trim_length = 200; 
                                        $values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mod3', true);
                                        if (is_array($values))
                                        {
                                        foreach($values as $value) {
                                        add_filter( 'custom_filter', 'wpautop' );
                                        echo '<p class="car-detail">'.apply_filters( 'custom_filter', $value ).'</p>';}   
                                        }       
                                        ?>  
                        </ul>                                                                   
                            <ul class="features active first feature-list">
                                <?php   if (get_the_terms($post->ID, 'features')) {
                                    $taxonomy = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'features');                                   
                                    foreach ($taxonomy as $taxonomy_term) {
                                    ?> <li><?php echo $taxonomy_term->name;?></li><?php }                       

                                    }
                                    ?>
                        </ul>                   

                        <ul class="video">
                            <li><?php $video_source = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_meta_box_source', true);
                                    $video_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_meta_box_videoid', true);                   
                                    if(($video_source == "vimeo") && !empty($video_id)){ ?>
                                    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $video_id; ?>?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=e275c7" width="478" height="310" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
                                    <?php } elseif(( $video_source == "youtube") && !empty($video_id)){ ?>
                                    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $video_id; ?>"  width="478" height="310" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                    <?php  } ?>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>


            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, without seeing the Javascript doing the show/hide mechanics, I'd suggest putting the "active" class on the first tab in the HTML and reloading the page.

Comment: thank you so much, that was useful, I can see the tab first, but to see the content within it I still need to click on the name of the tab, I'd like it to display the content automatically (now it's still showing the content from the other tab, the features one) [link](http://brateauto.ro/brate-auto/kit-brate-bmw-e34/)

Comment: Can you share the Javascript you're using?